# magento2 marketplace admin sync error

Tags: magento2

Trying to sync my marketplace account with magento2 admin panel and getting this error:

```
error setting certificate verify locations: 
CAfile: F:\xampp\ca-bundle\ca-bundle.crt CApath: none
```

CMS installed to localhost with https and ssl self-signed certificates, system - windows 7.

In php.ini added this:

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo="F:\xampp\ca-bundle\ca-bundle.crt"
openssl.cafile="F:\xampp\ca-bundle\ca-bundle.crt"
```

As I read for linux this problem according with permissions and directory should be readable. But my system installed at C:/ so for F:/ any directory should be available.
What's the issue related with? How to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this issue, let try this follow: 
 http://chrisschuld.com/2008/07/how-to-fix-the-curl-error-error-setting-certificate-verify-locations/

(this solution for linux)

With xampp on windows, let try: 
1. Open file server.crt in xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt 
2. Copy content of server.crt and paste to end of cacert.pem in xampp\perl\vendor\lib\Mozilla\CA 
3. add to end of php.ini: curl.cainfo="D:\xampp\perl\vendor\lib\Mozilla\CA\cacert.pem" 
4. Restart your Xampp

Reference: https://yikesplugins.com/support/knowledge-base/i-receive-the-error-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-why/

Comment: Thanks. I found cacert.pem on your first link and added it. Everything ok.